# Apache 2.4 Basic Authentication slow

Tags: apache, authentication

I have a Debian Stretch server running Apache 2.4.
I want to use Basic Authentication to allow only a few users access to the served directory.

My configuration:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "VPN Gateway Lpgin"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    <RequireAll>
        Require ip 192.168.2.0/24
        Require valid-user
    </RequireAll>
</Directory>
```

This does work, but all requests now take over a minute to complete.
If I comment out the authentication line  `Require valid-user` the requests are not slow at all.

```
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:08.272751 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 17970] [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01964: Connection to child 4 established (server localhost:443)
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:08.274989 2018] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 17970] mod_socache_shmcb.c(532): AH00835: socache_shmcb_retrieve (0xf3 -> subcache 19)
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:08.275157 2018] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 17970] mod_socache_shmcb.c(884): AH00849: match at idx=0, data=0
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:08.275267 2018] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 17970] mod_socache_shmcb.c(907): AH00850: shmcb_subcache_retrieve discarding expired entry
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:08.275292 2018] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 17970] mod_socache_shmcb.c(542): AH00836: leaving socache_shmcb_retrieve successfully
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:08.275632 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 17970] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2115): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername localhost found
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:08.275965 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 17970] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2115): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername localhost found
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:08.276057 2018] [core:debug] [pid 17970] protocol.c(2219): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH03155: select protocol from , choices=h2,h2-16,h2-15,h2-14,spdy/3.1,spdy/3,http/1.1 for server localhost
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:08.475832 2018] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 17970] mod_socache_shmcb.c(495): AH00831: socache_shmcb_store (0x0a -> subcache 10)
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:08.475990 2018] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 17970] mod_socache_shmcb.c(849): AH00847: insert happened at idx=0, data=(0:32)
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:08.476020 2018] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 17970] mod_socache_shmcb.c(854): AH00848: finished insert, subcache: idx_pos/idx_used=0/1, data_pos/data_used=0/198
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:08.476044 2018] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 17970] mod_socache_shmcb.c(516): AH00834: leaving socache_shmcb_store successfully
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:08.476100 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 17970] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2042): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:08.477457 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 17970] ssl_engine_kernel.c(366): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 4 (server localhost:443)
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:08.478096 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of Require ip 192.168.2.0/24: granted
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:08.478225 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:08.478257 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAll>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:08.478281 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:26.504306 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of Require ip 192.168.2.0/24: granted
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:26.504552 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : granted
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:26.504589 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAll>: granted
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:26.504620 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:26.505318 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of Require ip 192.168.2.0/24: granted
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:26.505459 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:26.505490 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAll>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:26.506120 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:44.539755 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of Require ip 192.168.2.0/24: granted
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:44.539958 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : granted
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:44.539994 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAll>: granted
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:44.540022 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:44.541340 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of Require ip 192.168.2.0/24: granted
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:44.541494 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:44.541583 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAll>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Dec 25 11:29:44.541615 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Dec 25 11:30:02.576180 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of Require ip 192.168.2.0/24: granted
[Tue Dec 25 11:30:02.576362 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : granted
[Tue Dec 25 11:30:02.576396 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAll>: granted
[Tue Dec 25 11:30:02.576426 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 17970] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Tue Dec 25 11:30:05.134078 2018] [deflate:debug] [pid 17970] mod_deflate.c(853): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH01384: Zlib: Compressed 13343 to 2899 : URL /index.php
[Tue Dec 25 11:30:10.141799 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 17970] ssl_engine_io.c(1044): [client 192.168.2.16:55447] AH02001: Connection closed to child 4 with standard shutdown (server localhost:443)
```

It seems to get stuck on authentication but I do not know why.
Tested different browsers and all of them display slow loading if Basic Authentication is enabled.
How to debug this?

EDIT: I also noticed Apache's CPU usage going through the roof hogging 100% while authenticating.

Comment: Looks like you are forcing Apache to do a IP lookup of the visitor and telling it can only use NAT addresses as those are not public IP's, If this is an intranet you would be better served with a firewall instead of this. If this is out there in the wild, then you should not be checking for a non public IP.

Comment: You are not wrong, I would probably benefit from using a firewall instead of letting Apache handle the IP's. But this does not affect the request speed as much as the BasicAuth seems to

Comment: Move the Require valid-user outside the Require all, it is forcing the check to loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the Require Valid user outside the Require all

```
Example

<Location "/secure">
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "private area"
    AuthBasicProvider  dbm
    AuthDBMType        SDBM
    AuthDBMUserFile    "/www/etc/dbmpasswd"
    Require            valid-user
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy Any
</Location>
```

Source [reference material used](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_basic.html)

Comment: Still does not solve the slow authentication & high cpu usage while doing the auth process

Comment: Try the ODS thing there.

Answer (score 0):

Apache2 slow basic auth / slow .htpasswd

it is because you using slow algoritm for password, just use md5 simple algoritm

```
htpasswd -c -m file login
```

Answer (score 0):

my Apache slowed it downed because of the bcrypt encryption of 17 times

```
htpasswd -B -C 17 -n RDG
```

(encypt with bcrypt 17 times and display the results on stdout which is the terminal for user RDG)

```
htpasswd -B -C 5 -n RDG
```

(encypt with bcrypt 5 times and display the results on stdout which is the terminal for user RDG)

When i take the RDG user with the 5 times encrypted password then Apache response as fast as usual. All other answers above didn't work for me.

Comment: I don't believe that `-C 5` is five times.  I believe it is more on the order of thirty-two times.  It's a logarithmic scale.  Increasing by one approximately doubles the number of repetitions.  And 10 is probably a more appropriate value than 5.  I would agree that 17 is probably overkill.